# Specializations or Branches of studies

Tags: exam-questions

Given sentence:

> Each  followed  his  natural bent  and  specialized  in  different  branches  of  study.

Question:

> They studied according to their natural bent, so their ____ are different.

Possible answers:

> 1. specializations
> 2. branches of studies

Which will be appropriate to answer?

Comment: Neither answer is inappropriate, and neither is incorrect. We need more information about this exam before we can offer useful guidance.

Answer (score 1):

In your example

> specializations

would be correct, however, another common phrasing is

> **areas** of study
>
> They studied according to their natural bent, so their **areas of study** are different.

Often each "*area*" is in a different "*branch*".